# WinJS Repeater table with rows (tr) wrapped in ItemContainer

Tags: microsoft-metro, repeater, winjs, windows-8.1

Is it possible to create table using Repeater control which has rows wrapped in ItemContainer controls? Something along the line:

```
    <table id="products">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                    <td>Billing Periodicity</td>
                    <td>Average Life Time (in months)</td>
                    <td>Is default</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-bind="winControl.data: products">
                <tr data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ItemContainer">
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: name"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: description"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: type"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: costPeriodicity"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: averageLifeTime"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: isDefault"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Given example throws exception at runtime:

```
Unable to get property 'children' of undefined or null reference
```

I' d like to use ItemContainer's functionality to make table rows clickable. Is my approach to the issue invalid? Is ItemContainer control wrong to use in that scenario?

Side note - if I apply ItemContainer control to table cells (td), evertything runs smoothly (they behave like windows8 - like clickable objects).

Comment: This seems not to work. The ItemContainer adds multiple hierarchies before the first td element is inserted. What you end up with is an invalid table.

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly declared data source for repeater, it should be declared as win-options not -win-bind, when you change it to:

```
 <tbody data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-options="{data: products}">
```

it should work with no problems.

Comment: Ok after doing it your way I don't get runtime exceptions anymore. Could you please explain why is that so? If I declare data source for repeater via data-win-bind and remove ItemContainer from tr, table renders correctly (data bind is valid), but as soon as I put ItemContainer inside tr, I get mentioned in question exception. I would really like to stick to data-bind approach because my app relies on viewModels (I'd rather bind to object's property than to global object in namespace with data-win-options).

Comment: Could you try specify repeater template as external one, not nested inside repeater? Maybe that would help?